# Aliases, variables and filenames

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix

I want to speed up the time it takes me to compile a file in C using aliases.

Here is my alias:

```
alias gccp="gcc -pendantic -Wall -ansi '$1'.c -o '$1'"
```

I try gccp p1 and expect it to run the command `gcc -pendantic -Wall -ansi p1.c -o p1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: aliases can't process arguments like $1. Convert to `function gccp { gcc - ... $1 ...; }`. Good luck.

Comment: actually they can. alias djang="django-admin.py startproject $1" works great.

Comment: @Dave: When you run `djang blah`, the shell substitutes `django-admin.py startproject` for `djang` and runs the command `django-admin.py startproject blah`.  The `$1` gets expanded to the empty string when evaluating the alias.

Comment: @Dave That is because the arguments just get appended to the end and the $1 (which gets converted the the empty string) happens to be at the end in that example

Comment: @Dave No, the argument at the end is ignored. However, an alias still processes everything at the end. The fact that it works in this particular case isn't an indicator that arguments are passed where the variable pragma is used. For example, try alias 'ls=ls --color=auto'. Arugments still functions normally, but you get color.

Comment: gotcha, so I can remove all my $1's from my aliases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias can't have a argument; in your case the $1 is nothing. You need to create a function that does this and export it.

**Edit**:

I made a mistake. Arguments are possible in bash aliases **but** they get assigned when the alias is created not when it is invoked. So in order to achive what you want add this function in your .bashrc file and restart bash.

```
function gccp()
{
        gcc -pendantic -Wall -ansi $1.c -o $1
}
```

**Even a further edit**

It all depends on what you term argument. For example if I add the following in my `.bashrc` file and restart bash

`alias blabla="echo $HOSTNAME"`

And I invoke `blabla` I get my hostname. But $HOSTNAME is not really an argument. It's a variable. An argument implies you are supplying the function/command you are calling with some sort of information. So by that definition, aliases **do not** take arguments.

Comment: Why does this alias work then?  alias subl="open -a /Applications/Sublime.app $1"

Answer (score 1):

Use `make` instead.

```
$ export CFLAGS=-pendantic -Wall -ansi
$ make p1
```

`make` will use its built-in pattern matching rules to do what you want.

If using environment variables is interacting with other things in an unwanted way, pass the `CFLAGS` value directly to `make` instead or write a one line makefile that defines `CFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases can't take arguments, see the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases).  When you invoke an alias with arguments, the arguments just get appended to the end of the command, since the shell is really only substituting the command name for the alias value.

Use a [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) instead:

```
gccp ()
{
    gcc -pendantic -Wall -ansi "$1".c -o "$1"
}
```